# Resolving constructor dependency on service used in NancyFX

Tags: ravendb, nancy, tinyioc

I have the following bootstrap

```
public class NancyBootStrapper: DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer container, NancyContext context)
    {
        base.ConfigureRequestContainer(container, context);

        var ravenSession = container.Resolve< IRavenSessionProvider >().GetSession();
        container.Register( ravenSession );
    }
}
```

When my Nancy app tries to instantiate BlogService using the following constructor

```
    public BlogService(IDocumentSession documentSession)
    {
        this.documentSession = documentSession;
    }
```

the application blows up stating that it can't resolve document session, I have also tried the following within my test method (removing the constructor injection).

```
    public void BuildCategories()
    {
        var container = TinyIoCContainer.Current;
        documentSession = container.Resolve< IDocumentSession >();
        documentSession.Store(new Category{Title = "test"});
        documentSession.Store(new Category{Title = ".net"});

        documentSession.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This also blows up, pointing out that it can't resolve documentSession.

Now this is the first time I have used either NancyFX or TinyIoC so I could be doing something fundamentally wrong though I should mention that the documentSession does resolve within a Nancy module..

Can any one offer a fix or some suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been playing & digging into both NancyFx and the TinyIoC code bases and have figured out how to fix this issue... I don't like the fix... but hay it works :)

Basically, I am creating a RavenDB document session in the bootstrapper method configureRequestContainer as it is best practice to use the request as your unit of work scope.

Unfortunately anything that is auto wired by tinyIoC within configureApplicationContainer does not have any constructor injection performed using the child container being used by the Nancy request (this includes those that are marked as MultiInstance or as PerRequestSingleton.

To get around this, you need to re-register any components that depend on your per request components within the same child container.

As I said, I don't like the fix, but it is ultimately a fix :)

Comment: The request containers are created, setup and destroyed per request so, yes, they're only available in that request by design. If you want to use the session outside of the nancy request then you'll either have to (a) use another session or (b) tie yourself to ASP.Net hosting and HttpContext and put it in there (ugh!) .. personally I'd choose (a), but they're the only options I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

When is the `BlogService` supposed to be instantiated? -My guess would be once for the application, in which case I believe you are registering the session in the wrong bootstrapper method, and should do it in `ConfigureApplicationContainer`.

Comment: Yup... the session is following the unit of work pattern and needs one session per request, thus me registering within ConfigureRequestContainer.
But that doesn't explain why I can resolve the session within the buildCategiries method at run time.. I would have thought the current version of TonyIoC would expose the request configuration with the application wide stuff :(